# "Hold the hope" vs. "keep the hope"

Tags: word-choice, verbs, collocation

I'm trying to decide whether I should use "hold the hope" or "keep the hope" in a composition I'm preparing. It seems to me they are equivalent. Personally I like "hold the hope" better because sounds less common. Also, it seems to me "hold the hope" would be more suitable where that what I'm hoping for is less likely to happen and "keep the hope" would be either, more likely or equally probable of happening than not happening. Is this assumption correct?

Comment: I read "hold the hope" as being similar in structure to "hold the pickles," which is to say, I read it as a request to avoid hope, rather than to keep it alive. "Hold onto hope" works, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using "the" before a noun refers to a specific object or concept, rather than a general abstract concept; for example, "the weather" is specific ("*the* weather today will be rainy"), while "weather" is not, ("Mild weather is to be expected at this time of year").

When you use "*the* xxx", in a sentence, then, you are referring to a *specific* "xxx", so the "xxx" should already have been introduced.

If the "xxx" (the hope, in this case) hasn't already been introduced, then you could do it in the phrase, for example "She was holding on to the hope that he would ask her to marry him".

Secondly, merely "holding" something intangible like hope is a metaphorical usage, and the statement doesn't really convey much unless you embellish or qualify it. "Keep hope alive" might be a better way of saying what you want to say, and is a well-used - and therefore well understood - expression.

Answer (score 1):

I am not very sure but I feel that when you ask someone to "hold the hope" it has a negative connotation, almost translating to "don't go ahead and hope until we are are more certain". Whereas when you tell someone to "keep the hope", that is very positive as in encouraging them to hope.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks everybody for their input. Yeah I was trying to use "hold the hope" in the sense of "keeping the hope" I'm concerned it could potentially be interpreted in an opposite way. Looks like adding "onto" would fix it? The sentence would go like: "But, at least, he can hold onto the hope, one of his kisses may be remembered". I didn't want to use "keep" because I'm using it earlier in the same paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

All I heard so far is "keep up the hope". I never heard "keep the hope" or "hold the hope" in the last 15 years in any film, music, documentary, etc. *I just noticed though how old this question is. :-)*

Answer (score 0):

I would say

> hold on to the hope.

The difference between *hold on to* (also spelled *hold onto*) and *hold* is that *hold on to* implies that you keep holding it for a long time.

From [Collins dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/hold-on-to):

> If you hold on to something, you keep it for a longer time than would normally be expected.